# Clear all revisions on ImpressPages 4.x

Tags: php, impresspages

While i creating website, a lot of revisions have accumulated and these revisons confuses the customer.
I want to clear all revisions before delivery website that I built for my customer.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Master branch on GitHub has just got few commits. Next release will have options to automatically remove old revisions. If you like, you can install ImpressPages from GitHub master branch and have those features immediately.
You can also update by replacing Ip folder from GitHub and pointing your browser to http://www.example.com/?pa=Update to update the database.

---

[image: New ImpressPages configuration options]

Comment: So excessive fast solution by you from ImpressPages! I like ImpressPages more now ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using IP 4.2.5 for the first time in my current project and encountered the same problem. After analyzing code base I found that the only time revisions are cleaned is on deletion of a page - you can see the corresponding code [here](https://github.com/impresspages/ImpressPages/blob/master/Ip/Internal/Content/Event.php#L110). Nevertheless, there exists a method called [`removeOldRevisions($days)`](https://github.com/impresspages/ImpressPages/blob/master/Ip/Internal/Revision.php#L172), which is actually never called. I think you would have to setup a [cron](http://www.impresspages.org/docs/cron) to execute this method. While getting above links from Github I discovered that there was a [recent commit](https://github.com/impresspages/ImpressPages/commit/bf6e491da3f8ba3e8c1a09c6c5d0ce797bcc0b2d) adding such a cron job, so maybe you just have to wait for release of 4.2.6 or clone from master.